# Which expression is more efficient and uses less memory?

Tags: javascript

1.

```
var array = [];array[10000] = 'value1';
```

2.

```
var dict = {10000:'value1'}; 
// more precise,should be
var dict = {};dict[10000] = 'value1';
```

Which expression is more efficient and uses less memory?

Is there any way we can watch the memory and CPU usage of the script?

I have tried using the Chrome Profiles tab to find that information, but I can't understand the following [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09TLg.png).

---

2015-06-10T14:37:41+0800 supplied

In node.js, try to use process.memoryUsage(), watch the memory usage.

Array Test

```
'use strict'
var start = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  var size = 20*1024*1024;
  var array = [];array[size] = 'value1';
};
console.log(process.memoryUsage());
var end = new Date().getTime();
console.log(end - start);
```

Dict Test with number key

```
'use strict'
var start = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  var size = 20*1024*1024;
  var dict = {};dict[size]{size:'value1'}; // size equal to a number 20971520 or a string like '20971520' can transform to number 20971520
};
console.log(process.memoryUsage());
var end = new Date().getTime();
console.log(end - start);
```

Dict Test with string key

```
'use strict'
var start = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  var size = 20*1024*1024;
  var dict = {};dict['s' + size] = 'value1'; // transform number to string
};
console.log(process.memoryUsage());
var end = new Date().getTime();
console.log(end - start);
```

Result

```
Array memory usage: {"rss":26570752,"heapTotal":17518848,"heapUsed":4943024}
Dict  number key:   { rss: 34238464, heapTotal: 23722496, heapUsed: 12038408 }
Dict  string key:   { rss: 26386432, heapTotal: 17518848, heapUsed: 6976632 }
Array cpu time: 4944ms
Dict number key: 6834ms
Dict string key: 382ms
```

V8 Engine alloced more memory to array than a dict with string key,but there is only a little difference in heapUsed. The unused memory of array was wasted.

About the cpu time,a big array with many empty elements and a dict with number key spent more time than a dict with string key.

> Warning: A string like '12380912830' which can transform to number, the dict treats it as a number,and will spend the biggest memory and cpu usage than any other way.

If want to store errorCode and errorMessage in script,such as

```
0 is success,
10001 is server Error
```

dict with string key is a better choose!

Comment: You'd have to make several thousand of each and see how much memory they use and you'd have to measure in several different browsers to actually know for sure.

Comment: What's more important is which option is the better data type for you.

Comment: Are these even the same?  Obviously (1.) creates is an array.  Does (2.) ?

Comment: Also, don't forget you can create an array of specific size right off.

Comment: @ErikEidt  i want store errorCode and errorMessage in script  and the errorCode may be not continuous.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for you suggest ,i have tried make some test in node.js,and reedited the question.

Comment: @Ja͢ck Maybe i should learn more knowledge about data structrue.

Comment: `var dict = {size:'value1'};` ... that should be `var dict = {}; dict[size] = 'value1';`.

Comment: @Ja͢ck A little change result to big difference，I have updated the question again! Thanks !

Answer (score -3):

(1) creates an array with 10001 keys (according to chrome console:)

[image]

(2) creates an object that only has 1 key (which is `{10000: "value1"}`)

[image]

So (2) is more efficient

Comment: Well, Chrome is going to make the first one into a sparse array (1000 items don't actually exist) so you would have to measure memory usage to actually know what you've concluded.  Your reasoning isn't enough to prove anything.  Might be right, might not.  Very well could depend upon the browser implementation.

Comment: I  think the more referable test should be populating an array with large quantity of elements and an object with the same number of keys. Then compare the performance of each of them.

Comment: "*(1) creates an array with 10001 keys*". No it doesn't. It creates an array with a single key of *10000* that has value of *value1* and a *length* of 10001, which is exactly what the console displays.

Comment: Wrong, see the ECMAScript specs for that (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5.1). It sets the length to 10001 but only 1 key.